# grid_display_settings issues with a single row

Tags: add-on, grid, fieldtype

I've had reported a problem with an add-on that settings for other fieldtypes aren't working when my fieldtype is enabled in a grid.

I've spent some time on this, and can only assume the problem is related to the `grid_display_settings()` function which I'm using to display add-on settings:

```
function grid_display_settings($data)
{

    return array(
        $this->grid_dropdown_row(
            "Load....",
            $this->field_name,
            $this->_get_grid_dropdown($data),
            array_get($data, 'list_type', null)
        )
    );

}
```

It all appears to be fine, in that I get no errors - however, on my grid field settings options, none of the other fieldtypes display their settings - I get a 'typeError: e.html(...) is null'. However, selecting my own field works as expected.

I've spent far too long on this bug already, so just putting this out there to see if anyone has come across this before?

Comment: Carl, does this happen with all other fieldtypes? (Native EE) I have run into instances in which another fieldtype has 'hijacked' the view state and not released it. That has played havoc on things in the past and can be a real booger to debug.

Comment: Yep - all I have running is my fieldtype and the default ones. If I uninstall my fieldtype, it's all fine. If I install it, I can select my fieldtype, but none of the others.

Comment: I know grid fields want each array item to be a string. Being that you're nesting the arrays, have you tried returning each inner as its own result and then building the array for the grid_dropdown_row in another method? Maybe implode the arrays or json_encode them???